# make-keyword-map in Clojure - Idiomatic?

Tags: clojure, lisp, idioms

I have been writing some Clojure recently, and I found myself using the following pattern frequently enough:

```
(let [x (bam)
      y (boom)]
  {:x x
   :y y})
```

So I went ahead and wrote the following macro:

```
(defmacro make-keyword-map [& syms]
  `(hash-map ~@(mapcat (fn [s] [(keyword (name s)) s]) syms)))
```

With that, code now looks like:

```
(let [x (bam)
      y (boom)]
  (make-keyword-map x y)
```

Would this sort of macro be considered idiomatic? Or am I doing something wrong, and missing some already established pattern to deal with something of this sort?

Answer (score 7):

Note, that you can also replace all of:

`(let [x (bam)
      y (boom)]
  {:x x
   :y y})`

with just:

`{:x (bam)
 :y (boom)}`

which will evaluate to the same thing.

---

If your `let` expressions depend on one another, then how about a macro like so:

```
(defmacro make-keyword-map [& let-body]
  (let [keywords-vals (flatten (map (juxt keyword identity)
                               (map first (partition 2 let-body))))]
    `(let ~(vec let-body)
       (hash-map ~@keywords-vals))))
```

that way `(make-keyword-map x (foo 1) y (bar 2) z (zoom x))` expands to:

```
(clojure.core/let [x (foo 1) y (bar 2) z (zoom x)]
  (clojure.core/hash-map :x x :y y :z z))
```

So something like this would work:

```
user=> (defn foo [x] (+ x 1))
#'user/foo
user=> (defn bar [x] (* x 2))
#'user/bar
user=> (defn zoom [x] [(* x 100) "zoom!"])
#'user/zoom
user=> (make-keyword-map x (foo 1) y (bar 2) z (zoom x))
{:z [200 "zoom!"], :y 4, :x 2}
```

Not sure how idiomatic that is, but it also saves you a `let`, compared to your original example.

Comment: This is an overly simplified example. Often I need to use those local bindings to produce other local bindings. e.g. `(let [x (bam) y (boom x) z (zoom x)] ...)`. Because maps can't refer to other keys inside themselves (because they aren't "objects" in that sense)

Comment: I think this new `make-keyword-map` is much cleaner. The original seemed to be operating at an awkward level of abstraction, where the definition of the map is intertwined with the names of local variables.

Comment: Shorter version of same: `(defmacro make-keyword-map [& bindings] (let [ks (take-nth 2 bindings)] \`(let [~@bindings] (hash-map ~@(interleave (map keyword ks) ks)))))`