# Define clojure hash map without duplicating tokens

Tags: clojure

I'd like to return a hash-map like so:

```
(fn [foo bar] {:foo foo :bar bar})
```

Is it possible to do that without repeating the names? Something like how `let` allows this:

```
(let [{:keys [foo bar]} args]
   (...))
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/20913319/1756702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro:

```
(defmacro some-hash-thing [& vals]
  (zipmap (map keyword vals) vals))
```

And in use:

```
(let [a 4, b 5]
  (some-hash-thing b a))
;; => {:a 4, :b 5}
```

Comment: I'd suggest stealing the names from @noisesmith answer: `as-keymap` and `names` are way better.

Comment: The syntax-quote unquote is extraneous - they cancel each other out.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @A.Webb. Obviously, I didn't clean it up as much as I could from all my REPL experimenting. I've edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defmacro as-keymap [& names] `(conj {} ~@(map (juxt keyword symbol) names)))
```